# Meteor Tabular errors on initialization

Tags: meteor, tabular

I'm following along the guide to setup Meteor Tabular v2.1.2 ([guide](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-tabular)). I have added the package and installed the theming packages. I'm using Meteor v2.8.0 and the project is a Blaze-based project.

In `client/main.js`, I set up the library as instructed.

```js
import { $ } from 'meteor/jquery';
import dataTablesBootstrap from 'datatables.net-bs';
import 'datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css';

import "../imports/ui/body";

dataTablesBootstrap(window, $);
```

Now when I go to the browser, there is this error:
[image: Browser Error]

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

So after serious debugging , I discovered it is enough to just import the DataTable module as such after installing it with npm

```
    import { $ } from 'meteor/jquery';
    import 'datatables.net-bs';
    import 'datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css';

    import "../imports/ui/body";

//  You don't need the code previously here .
```

You can now setup you DataTable as such

```
$(element).DataTable(//Your config object)
```